# Mapping array of props objects reduce(sum) values in objects in React

Tags: reactjs, reduce, semantic-ui-react, array.prototype.map

I have multiple props objects and pass them into an array.
each object contains point value. I'm trying to sum all values in the objects and pass the result into Semantic-ui-react Statistics component.

```
const withoutSpousePointsArray = [
            withoutSpouseAgePoint, 
            withoutSpouseLoePoint, 
            withoutSpouseOlpPoint, 
            withoutSpouseOlp2Point, 
            withoutSpouseExpPoint, 
            BwithSpouseLoePoint,
            BwithSpouseOlpPoint,
            BwithSpouseExpPoint,
            skillEducation1Point,
            skillEducation2Point,
            skillFwe1Point,
            skillFwe2Point,
            skillCertificatePoint,
            additionalPoint,
];
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    // core withSpouse states
    withSpouseAgePoint: state.withSpouseAge,
    withSpouseLoePoint: state.withSpouseLoe,
    withSpouseOlpPoint: state.withSpouseOlp,
    withSpouseOlp2Point: state.withSpouseOlp2,
    withSpouseExpPoint: state.withSpouseExp,
    // core withoutSpouse
    withoutSpouseAgePoint: state.withoutSpouseAge,
    withoutSpouseLoePoint: state.withoutSpouseLoe,
    withoutSpouseOlpPoint: state.withoutSpouseOlp,
    withoutSpouseOlp2Point: state.withoutSpouseOlp2,
    withoutSpouseExpPoint: state.withoutSpouseExp,
    // Spouse factor
    BwithSpouseLoePoint: state.BwithSpouseLoe,
    BwithSpouseOlpPoint: state.BwithSpouseOlp,
    BwithSpouseExpPoint: state.BwithSpouseExp,
    // skill transferability factors
    skillEducation1Point: state.skillEducation1,
    skillEducation2Point: state.skillEducation2,
    skillFwe1Point: state.skillFwe1,
    skillFwe2Point: state.skillFwe2,
    skillCertificatePoint: state.skillCertificate,
    // Additional
    additionalPoint: state.additional,
});
```

Since there are multiple objects I `.map()` the points value first and `.reduce()` to sum all the values. the result showed like [image: this]

so I added `parsInt()` the default number set to 0 but when I dispatch the action, It showed me many 0s again and the number does not add up correctly.

```
const withoutSpousePointSum = 
        withoutSpousePointsArray.map(points => points.point)
        .reduce((acc, curr) => [parseInt(acc + curr)]);
```

```
<Points key={shortid.generate()} color={"orange"} value={withoutSpousePointSum} label={"Points"} />
```

Is there a solution to work this correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Did you make sure that `withoutSpousePointsArray` is filled correctly at the point of you starting the mapping process?

Comment: @xDreamCoding all required objects are in the Array and tried `push()` to add the object into an array.  the result is the same. so did you mean by adding the object into array process is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things about your reduce function:

- `reduce` should parse only the current value
- `parseInt` should pass the base as second param to force decimal parse
- `reduce` should pass in the initial value as the second param

-

```
const withoutSpousePointSum = 
  withoutSpousePointsArray
    .map(points => points.point)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr, 10), 0);
```

Comment: this work like a charm. Also, Thank you for the explanation. parse Only the current value. good to know.